# Removing certain elements from array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need my code to look backwards through an array, say: `[20, 15, 9, 2, 11, 9, 11, 10, 3]`.

It needs to find the elements that satisfies to be in an interval created by an element + - 2.

Ex. 3 creates the interval [1-5] since the next element is 10 its higher than the interval. We move to the element 10 which creates the interval [8-12] we see that 11, 9, 11, 9 and 10 itself is in that interval, add them to new array. (elements higher than the interval should make the code break, smaller elements are okay).

input ex: `[20, 15, 9, 2, 11, 9, 11, 10, 3]`
output ex: `[9, 2, 11, 9, 11, 10, 3] or [9, 11, 9, 11, 10]`

input ex: `[20, 15, 9, 2, 11, 20, 11, 10, 3]`
output ex: `[11, 10, 3]` or `[11, 10]`

I have tried many approaches to this, and since i am pretty new im not very experienced on whats able to do within an array. I have looked around the internet with little luck.

What i have come up with so far is this:

```
List<Integer> thetops = new ArrayList<Integer>();
double lowerFactor = 0.8;
double upperFactor = 1.2;


for(int k = tops.size()-1; k > 0; k--){
    double lowerLimit = tops.get(k) * lowerFactor;
    double upperLimit = tops.get(k) * upperFactor;

    if (tops.get(k-1) > upperLimit){
        k=k-1;

        }
    if (tops.get(k) >= lowerLimit && tops.get(k) <= upperLimit){
        thetops.add(tops.get(k));
    }
}
```

What im trying to do is to choose the last element, creating an interval from that value, if the next element is higher than the interval move to that element. But if the next element is in that interval add it to the new array.

Comment: besides the fact that this looks a lot like homework, i don`t understand your question at all. please be more explicit what the relation between the numbers is

Comment: Looks like an interesting homework puzzle, if only we understood it.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to accomplish.  What do you mean by "within and interval".  What interval? Can you give some examples? i.e. kind of test cases so that we can help you?

Comment: Its actually not homework, just me puzzling around with arrays :) Seems like its hard to explain. Im trying my best.

By interval i mean that from the first element, 3, i create a interval using the factors in the code, so i get the interval [2,4 - 3,6]. I check if the next element is in that interval, add it to new array. if its higher i increment and check from there. if its lower it can stay. 

This is getting more complicated as im trying to explain it..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove all values higher than a specific threshold and remove duplicates as well, correct?

If that's the case, then try and use a `SortedSet` (or `SortedMap`), add all the values to the set which will remove the duplicates and then get the head set of that sorting set, i.e. get all values smaller than the threshold (if the threshold should be contained as well, pass threshold + 1 to the `headSet(...)` method).

If you need to retain the sorting as in the array, you might want to use a map and use the values as keys and the array index as values.

Comment: First part is correctly understanded but i dont want to remove duplicates + i must not change the order in the array.

Comment: @LarsAllan when you don't want to remove duplicates, why would the output for `[20, 15, 9, 2, 11, 20, 11, 10, 3]` be `[11, 10, 3]`?

Comment: because since the element with value 20 is greater than the interval created from 10 [8-12]. The code should break there.. at least thats what im trying to do..